# SQL replace syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have a select query that gets a field and displays it with a custom name, ex acctID as ACCOUNT ID. If the data for this field is a varchar but is all numbers with decimals ex 000.887.4456.000000, how do I use replace in that select query to remove the decimals from a field like this?

Comment: So desired result would be `0008874456000000`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(acctID, '.', '') AS ACCOUNT_ID FROM TABLE
```

[REPLACE function reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

Comment: I'd be careful about double quotes: SQL Server be default will read this as column names because of SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

Comment: @gbn - Thanks! Didn't know that. Edited answer as suggested.

Comment: I used single quotes, I thought it may have been more complicated than this but I'm still learning....thank you for your help, I'll select yours as the answer when allowed!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ex.acctID,
    REPLACE(ex.acctID, '.', '')
FROM
    Mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACE(acctID, '.','') AS AccountID
```